# How To Play M3u8 Links With A User Agent On ExoPlayer

Tags: android, user-agent, exoplayer

I have This Link

## EXTVLCOPT:http-user-agent=2139jkjks

http://51.159.3.14:8081/live/FILMAKSION/playlist.m3u8
And i want to play it inside my android app.
It only supports single links who are entered from a panel.
anyone has any idea how i can play the links with user agent please

Answer (score 0):

Please check the official Exoplayer Demo because there you have this method that I think is what you want customize:

```
  public HttpDataSource.Factory buildHttpDataSourceFactory() {
return new DefaultHttpDataSourceFactory(userAgent);
```

}